# popBackStack() returns same fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to when button clicked to return to previous fragment. This is how I create fragment:

```
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, statisticsSpecificStudentFragment)
                        .addToBackStack("StatisticsStudentOverallFragment")
                        .commit();
```

This is how I try and return to this fragment, from whom I started new fragment:

```
        btDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
```

All that happends is that it reloads current fragment, like I added current one to stack but I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> popBackStack("StatisticsStudentOverallFragment")

Or

> addToBackStack(null)

and keep popBackStack() like you have it already.

Comment: I would but I call this fragment from many differen ones, so I really need it to be with stack

Comment: Yea I was actually looing at wrong fragment when testing it, this works fine, enjoy  some rating.